# Plotting result of groupBy in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to plot something that is the result of dividing two groupbys using Python/Pandas. Here is the code I have so far:

```
#total number of posts per name
totalCount = df.groupby('Name')['uniq_id'].count()


#find total number of feeling words per name
feelingCount = df.groupby('Name')['Feeling_words'].sum().apply(lambda 
feel: len(feel)) 

#average number of feeling words for posts, per name
ratio = feelingCount/totalCount
```

The output from ratio looks something like:

```
Alice            0.333333
John             3.629630
Maya             0.333333
Waldo            1.076923
```

I don't really understand how the results from taking the ratio are stored, and am therefore not really sure how plotting a bar graph of my results would work. I simply want each name to be at the x-axis and the y-axis to be the computed ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ratio` is a pandas `Series`. Just plot it:

```
ratio.plot(kind='bar')
```